# How do i set action in form?

Tags: laravel, forms, routes

I am trying to compare the specs of two different motorcycles from a table.

```
Select first bike
<form action ="{{ route('compare.get') }}" method="get">
<div class="first_bike" style="width:200px;">
  <select name="bike1">
  @foreach($bikes as $bike)
    <option value="{{ $bike->id }}"> {{ $bike->name }}</option>
  @endforeach  
  </select>
</div>
<br>
Select second bike
<div class="second_bike" style="width:200px;">
  <select>
  @foreach($bikes as $bike)
    <option value="{{ $bike->id }}"> {{ $bike->name }}</option>
  @endforeach  
  </select>
</div>

<br>
<button type="button"> Compare </button> 
</form>
```

I created two for each loops for bike1 and bike2 that select all the bikes from the table. As I can only access the `$bike`property inside the loop, how can I send the selected bikes to get controller and access the information to compare them?.
Is there any better idea to do this?

Comment: you should give the second select a name, but this would work ... you would access those inputs like any other inputs

Comment: thanks for mentioning. The get method in controller expects parameters. How do i specify them  in the action of the form? I created foreach loop to display all the bikes in table. the form tag is outside the loop. How can I pass the selected bike then ? I am stucked

Comment: that is what the form inputs are for (selects), they are request inputs ... the GET method uses the query string to pass the data, these are not route parameters

Comment: if you need the URL to change based on these inputs you would need to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

First off, add a `name` attribute to the second `select` element. After that, you should be able to access both fields using either `$_GET['bike1']` or `request()->bike1` (as you seem to be using Laravel).